# gnuplot stdin, how to plot two lines?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to produce a plot with two lines using data taken from stdin.  I have a file "test.csv":

```
0,1.1,2
1,2,3
2,6,4
4,4.6,5
5,5,6
```

I've been trying to plot this with commands like,

```
$ cat test | gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator \",\"; plot '-' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines;"
```

But no matter what I try I get,

```
line 5: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

I assume this is because for the second line, stdin has already been exhausted.  Is there a way to get gnuplot to take data from each column of stdin for different plots?

Thanks.

Comment: Could a `set` command be used instead of the `using` clause? Maybe that could allow a use of `replot`?...Hmm, probably not ideal; we want one `plot` command here, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "-" is used to specify that the data follows the plot command. So if you use it, you'll need to do something like:

```
echo "set datafile separator \",\"; plot '-' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines;" | cat - datafile.dat | gnuplot -p
```

(Quoting above probably needs to be escaped).

What're you looking for is this:

```
plot '< cat -'
```

Now, you can do:

```
cat test | sed ... | gnuplot -p "plot '< cat -' using ..."
```

Note that you might need to feed in the input data via stdin multiple times if you're using options with plot, like so:

```
cat testfile testfile | gnuplot -p "plot '< cat -' using 1, '' using 2"
```

In the above case, testfile must end with a line that has the sole character 'e' in it.

[Manual reference](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-13200034.1.7)

Answer (score 12):

I managed to work around this by sending the data twice, terminated by am "e" on it's own line after each block.
So your input should look like

```
set datafile separator ","; plot '-' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines
0,1.1,2
1,2,3
2,6,4
4,4.6,5
5,5,6
e
0,1.1,2
1,2,3
2,6,4
4,4.6,5
5,5,6
e
```

Comment: Is there a way to put the data from each plot on one line. e.g. : `0,1.1,2  1,2,3  2,6,4  4,4.6,5  5,5,6  e`

Answer (score 11):

Gnuplot can read from stdin, but for each plot statement, a new data set is required. The following works fine:

```
cat test.csv | gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator ','; plot '-' using 1:2 w l"
```

The error appears as soon as you append the second plot command with `, '' using 1:3`. For this you need to send the data again as the first data set isn't stored interally for reuse. So for you two plot commands, the following snippet works fine:

```
echo 'e' | cat test.csv - test.csv | gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator ','; plot '-' using 1:2 w l, '' using 1:3 w l"
```

That writes the data file twice, separated by an `e` which indicates the end of the data for the first plot command.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try converting the csv file to space separated (assuming no of the records span multiple lines) by piping it through `sed` instead of setting the separator:

```
cat test | sed 's/,/ /g' | gnuplot -p -e "plot '-' using ..."
```

Comment: Oh, I think I just saw it. You're missing the dash in the second part of the plot command. Make it `plot '-' using 1:2 with lines, '-' using 1:3 with lines;` and I think it should work.

Comment: Nope, sorry.  The missing dash just means "Use the same file as previously".

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [chart](https://github.com/marianogappa/chart)? Your case would be as easy as:

```
cat test | chart line ','
```

And would give you:

[image: line chart]

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but extremely useful to me. Thanks! I get tired of having to look up gnuplot junk every time I want to plot some simple data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an old question but I've found an interesting solution based on the other answers:

```
cat filename | awk -- '{print $0} END{print "e"}' | tee -i -a - -
```

The output would be:

```
"contents of filename"
e
"contents of filename"
e
"contents of filename"
e
```

Now `cat` and `awk` work as usual, the utility `tee` on the other hand allows us to copy the standard output piped from the previous command to a file, but this file can be *stdin* itself so we can make many copies of it, by specifying *n* times `-` after `-a`.

The option `-i` stops it being interrupted by signals during the copy, `-a` tells it to append the input to standard input without overwriting and then write the whole thing to *stdout*.

For reference take a look at [Tee Utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html)

Comment: Using the `tee` utility seems nice, but your command line as you posted it doesn't work at all for me. I tried both with `gawk` and `mawk`, but I get only three `e` as output (I used a real file in the `cat`).

Comment: you're right i forgot to add {print $0} in the awk script, i'll edit the answer to fix it

Comment: `tee` writes to all its arguments, including stdout, if there are enough lines the data will get intermixed. You can see this by sending many lines to tee eg. with seq: `seq 10000 | tee -i -a -`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works when I do:

```
set datafile separator ','
plot "test.csv" using 1:2 with lines
```

it seems that you used "," for datafile separator instead of ','

Comment: The quotes don't make a difference.  The problem is with `stdin`, not with the separator.  In your example, you specified `test.csv`, which indeed works fine but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot seems to need random access (i.e. not stdin), so I think you're stuck with

```
# explicitly open "test" file
$ gnuplot -p -e "set datafile separator \",\"; plot 'test' using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines;"
```

Comment: Right you are, it can read from stdin, but you still need a temporary file, so why not pass it in?

Comment: Right, it doesn't make much sense, if you have a file anyway. But it explains the error :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following, since adding '-' did not work for me:

```
 cat filename | awk -- '{print $0} END{print "e"}' | tee -i -a /dev/stdout /dev/stdout
```