# Plotting data with gnuplot from stdin

Tags: cmd, gnuplot

I have simple python script (smazat.py) that generate some data

```
for i in range(50):
    print i, i-20
```

I can make images in windows command line with following command

```
smazat.py | gnuplot -e "set term png;p '-'" > smazat.png
```

however when use gnuplot script with the same commands like this

```
smazat.py | gnuplot smazat.gp > smazat.png
```

it does not work. What's happening?

Comment: Use `plot '< cat -'`, see [pipe plot data to gnuplot script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17576571/2604213).

Comment: possible duplicate of [pipe plot data to gnuplot script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543386/pipe-plot-data-to-gnuplot-script)

Comment: `plot '< cat -'` does not work in windows

Comment: Ups, I overlooked that you are on Windows. See my answer for a little python script which passes stdin to stdout and can be used like cat in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Unix system, you can use

```
plot `< cat -`
```

to achieve this (see [pipe plot data to gnuplot script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17576571/2604213)).

On Windows, and since you're using python anyway, you can write a small `cat.py` python script which passes stdin to stdout:

Script `cat.py`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, file=sys.stdout, end='')
```

Plot file `plot.gp`

```
set term png
plot '< python cat.py'
```

And then call this with

```
python smazat.py | gnuplot plot.gp > smazat.png
```