# How do I plot a column of a file from the command line, e.g. using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file stats.txt with a numeric column "age" that is the 3rd column. 
How do I plot the column "age" from the command line?

I want to be able to do something like :

```
    cat stats.txt | awk '{print $3}' | plot
```

What's the cleanest way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

To plot from the command line just do

```
gnuplot -persist -e "plot 'stats.txt' using 0:3"
```

Comment: What if instead of stats.txt I want the output for a script ?

Comment: @user196711 Then you must use something like `./script.sh | gnuplot -persist -e "plot '<cat' using 1:2"`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17543386/2604213