# piping to gnuplot, getting "no valid points error"

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to pipe a data file to gnuplot. The data file looks like:

```
Type1 67 45
Type2 78 34
```

My gp script is:

```
set terminal dumb
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set auto x
set style fill solid border rgb "black"
set yrange [0:*]
plot "<cat" using 2:xtic(1), "" u 3:xtic(1)
```

When I type `cat test.dat | gnuplot script.gp` I get the warning

> line 7: Skipping data file with no valid points

and a graph of the first data column is shown, but without the second.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Simplify your problem. Remove the second plot (you are aware that you cannot re-use the data, only the actual file-name?), remove the histogram doing a simple x-y "plot using 2:3 w l". Isn't it a bit unorthodox to have two "cat command

Comment: Maybe you find your solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543386/pipe-plot-data-to-gnuplot-script