# Gnuplot prints differently when piping

Tags: command-line, gnuplot

I have file like this:

```
662.0,,9624
663.0,,9625
771.0,9624,
772.0,,9626
912.0,9625,
913.0,,9627
1083.0,9626,
1083.0,,9628
1174.0,9627,
1175.0,,9629
```

And when I use gnuplit console, it prints as expected:

```
set datafile separator ',';
plot 'data-exchange.log' using 1:2 pt 7 ps 2, '' using 1:3 pt 7 ps 2;
```

[image]

However, when I do the same when piping, it doesn't plot as expected:

```
cat data-exchange.log | gnuplot -p -e 'set datafile separator ","; plot "<cat" using 1:2 pt 7 ps 2, "" using 1:3 pt 7 ps 2;'
```

[image]

Not sure why is that...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981279/how-to-make-several-plots-from-the-same-standard-input-data-in-gnuplot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make several plots from the same standard input data in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981279/how-to-make-several-plots-from-the-same-standard-input-data-in-gnuplot)